# Best way to fill NULL values with conditions using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So for example I have a data looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[np.NaN, '1-5'], [np.NaN, '26-100'], ['Yes', 'More than 1000'], ['No', '26-100'], ['Yes', '1-5']], columns=['self_employed', 'no_employees'])
df

    self_employed   no_employees
0   nan                  1-5
1   nan                 26-100
2   Yes            More than 1000
3   No                  26-100
4   Yes                  1-5
```

And I'm trying to fill the NULL value based on the condition that:

```
If no_employees is '1-6' then 'Yes', otherwise 'No'
```

I was able to complete this using the dictionary such as:

```
self_employed_dict = {'1-5': 'Yes', '6-25': 'No', '26-100': 'No', '100-500': 'No', 'More than 1000':'No', '500-1000': 'No'}
df['self_employed'] = df['self_employed'].fillna(df['no_employees'].map(self_employed_dict))
```

But I wanted to know if there is a better, simple way of doing this. In this example, I had to write the dictionary for myself to map it, so how can I do this in the smart way?

The expected output looks like this:

```
    self_employed   no_employees
0   Yes                  1-5
1   No                 26-100
2   Yes            More than 1000
3   No                  26-100
4   Yes                  1-5
```

Comment: your `self_employed` column does not change. kindly post your expected output

Comment: @sammywemmy Ha that's weird..  I used np.NaN for the nan value in the example dataframe...

Comment: Try [numpy where](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) : ``df.assign(self_employed=np.where(df.no_employees == "1-5", "Yes", "No"))``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [fillna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) is the right way to go, but instead you could do:

```
values = df['no_employees'].eq('1-5').map({False: 'No', True: 'Yes'})
df['self_employed'] = df['self_employed'].fillna(values)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
  self_employed    no_employees
0           Yes             1-5
1            No          26-100
2           Yes  More than 1000
3            No          26-100
4           Yes             1-5
```

Comment: Works great. upvoted. I feel however that it is a longer process compared to numpy where(three steps)

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on your pandas version. There are two cases:

1. Pandas Verion 1.0.0+, to check

   `print(df['self_employed'].isna()).any()` will returns `False` **and/or**

   `type(df.iloc[0,0])` returns type `str`.

   In this case all elements of your dataframe are of type string and `fillna()` will not work. This is because the `fillna()` function will not react on the string `nan` so you can use `update()`:

```
helper = df['no_employees'].eq('1-5').map({False: 'No', True: 'Yes'}).to_frame('self_employed')
df.update(other=helper, filter_func=lambda x: df['self_employed'].eq('nan'))
```

2. Older Pandas Version there data types can be mixed up, this means

   `print(df['self_employed'].isna()).any()` will returns `True` **and/or**

   `type(df.iloc[0,0])` returns type `float`

```
values = df['no_employees'].eq('1-5').map({False: 'No', True: 'Yes'})
df['self_employed'] = df['self_employed'].fillna(values)
```

This will get you:

```
  self_employed    no_employees
0           Yes             1-5
1            No          26-100
2           Yes  More than 1000
3            No          26-100
4           Yes             1-5
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
pd.fillna(0)
```

it fills `NA`/`NaN` values with the value you want (in this case `0`).

[See more details here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html)

Comment: The questioneer don't wand to fill the `NaN`with zero.